# Bind a DataGrid to the selectedrow object of a second datagrid, WPF Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I have a datagrid that is bound to a BindableCollection, this is working properly, every repair order I add to the BindableCollection shows in the Datagrid.

I have a second Datagrid on the same view for "WriteOffs", Each "RepairOrder" has a property of BindableCollection.

What I am trying to do is bind the WriteOff DataGrid to the WriteOffs of the selected row. So every time the user selects a row in the "RepairOrder" datagrid the write offs stored in the writeoff property is shown in the WriteOff datagrid.

What is the best way to handle this?

RepairOrder class:

```
public string ControlNumber { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public string Schedule { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public List<WriteOff> WriteOffs { get; set; }



        public RepairOrder(string CN, string SC, double VL)
        {
            ControlNumber = CN;
            Schedule = SC;
            Value = Math.Round(VL,2);
            Note = null;
            WriteOffs = new List<WriteOff>();
        }

        public RepairOrder()
        {

        }

        public void AddWriteOff(WriteOff WO)
        {
            WriteOffs.Add(WO);
        }

        public BindableCollection<WriteOff> GetWriteOffs()
        {
            BindableCollection<WriteOff> temp = new BindableCollection<WriteOff>();
            foreach (var item in WriteOffs)
            {
                temp.Add(item);
            }
            return temp;
        }

        public static RepairOrder FromCSV(string CSVLine, string Sched)
        {
            string[] values = CSVLine.Split(',');
            RepairOrder rep = new RepairOrder();
            rep.ControlNumber = values[2];
            rep.Value = Math.Round(double.Parse(values[5]),2);
            rep.Age = int.Parse(values[4]);
            rep.Schedule = Sched;
            return rep;
        }
```

The XML for the Data grid showing the repair orders:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                <DataGrid  x:Name="ScheduleGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding RepairOrders}" CanUserSortColumns="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedRepairOrder}" SelectionMode="Single">

                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Schedule" Binding="{Binding Schedule}" Width="75" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Control Number" Binding="{Binding ControlNumber}" Width="110" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" Width="50" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value, StringFormat=C}" Width="75" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Note" Binding="{Binding Note}" Width="*"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Border>
```

XML for the Data grid for the write-offs:

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5,2,5,5">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="Write Off List" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"/>
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding WriteOffs}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account" Binding="{Binding Account}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" Width="200" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding WriteOffAmount}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
```

I was thinking of making an event when the user selects a row, but I can't seem to find a way to get the value if the selected row into the ViewModel method.

I can't seem to find a clear tutorial or post on exactly how to hand this situation.

What is the easiest way to accomplish my final goals?

Comment: So you are trying this, when I select item in one `DataGrid` with index (lets say 2) it should select item in second `DataGrid` with same index?

Comment: No When the user selects the item in the Repair Order datagrid "x:Name=ScheduleGrid" the write off data grid populates with a bindablecollection of writeoffs with-in the POCO's that populate "ScheduleGrid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this is the way I would do...

Instead of `SelectedIndex` on your `ScheduleGrid DataGrid` you need to use `SelectedItem`.
So your `XAML` would look like this:

```
 <DataGrid  x:Name="ScheduleGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding RepairOrders}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRepairOrder} ...."
```

Not to the `ViewModel`
Now you need to make the `SelectedItem` property, or `SelectedRepairOrder`.
The property should look like this:

```
 private RepairOrder _selectedRepairOrder;
 public RepairOrder SelectedRepairOrder
        {
            get { return _selectedRepairOrder; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedRepairOrder == value) return;
                _selectedRepairOrder = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedRepairOrder);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => WriteOffsCollection);
            }
        }
```

Second, since we have two `DataGrids` we need also two `Collections`.
The `ScheduleGrid` should have a `Collection` who looks like this:

```
   private BindableCollection<RepairOrder> _repiarOrdersCollection;
        public BindableCollection<RepairOrder> RepairOrders
        {
            get { return _repiarOrdersCollection; }
            set
            {
                _repiarOrdersCollection = value;
            }
        }
```

And the `WriteOffs DataGrid` collection should be like this:

```
        public BindableCollection<WriteOff> WriteOffs
        {
            get
            {
                return GetWriteOffs();
            }
        }
```

Okay... now what happens... As you can see in your `SelectedRepairOrder` property, after it changes, it will notify your `WriteOffs` collection that it has changed. And since we are newer setting the value of its `DataGrid`, we don't need any `setter`. 
Now one thing is missing. Since you have two collections, I believe that you want after selecting item from one collection to filter the items on other collection? Right? If yes, the you need to extend your `GetWriteOffs()` method, to have parameters of some king, `string, int...` and inside it filter your data.

Comment: Thank You, It was the "how to handle the "BindableCollection<WriteOff>" collection I was getting confused on.  Now one more issue.  I am not used to building the GUI portion of an app in XAML.  I am used to building the GUI in Java as an actual class, Its easy to access GUI elements from another class.  All the tutorials I have watched people are accessing the XAML elements by their "x:Name" value as in "ScheduleGrid" in my case.  I have been fighting with accessing the grid by its x:Name from the viewModel class.  What am I missing that allows me access to the XAML x:Name?

Comment: Okay wait, you are not using any pattern like `MVVM`?

Comment: I am, I am using Caliburn Micro. with a view, viewmodel and model folders and the respective views ext......  And then as I was writing this I realized in your example I don't need to access the element by its name since the "SelectedItem" is already bound to a property.......  Thank You @arcticwhite