# Auto updating a datagrid - WPF C# Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

@arcticwhite did an amazing job helping me get to the point I am now in this post:
[Bind a DataGrid to the selectedrow object of a second datagrid, WPF Caliburn.Micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592712/bind-a-datagrid-to-the-selectedrow-object-of-a-second-datagrid-wpf-caliburn-mic)

I have been able to get it working with one small glitch.  First, let me tell you what the app is supposed to do.  I have a Datagrid that is populated with repair order information.  Each repair order class has a list of "WriteOffs" (write-offs having their own class.

The app has a second Datagrid that shows all the write-offs for the selected repair order.  Using arcticwhite's assistance I was able to get this working.

My problem is, when I add a new write-off to the selected repair order, it does not automatically show in the write-offs Datagrid.

In the ShellModelView (main window) this is the code for the collection that the write off Datagrid is bound to:

```
public BindableCollection<WriteOff> WriteOffs
        {
            get {

                return GetWriteOffs();
            }

        }
```

The method call in the Write-offs collection

```
public BindableCollection<WriteOff> GetWriteOffs()
        {
            BindableCollection<WriteOff> temp = new BindableCollection<WriteOff>();
            if (SelectedRepairOrder != null)
            {
                if (SelectedRepairOrder.GetMyWriteOffs() != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in SelectedRepairOrder.GetMyWriteOffs())
                    {
                        temp.Add(item);

                    }
                    return temp;
                }
                else { return null; }
            }
            else { return null; }
        }
```

The below line returns a "List" if write offs - that's what the loop is for.

```
SelectedRepairOrder.GetMyWriteOffs()
```

The property the selected repair order is bound to:

```
public RepairOrder SelectedRepairOrder
        {
            get { return _selectedRepairOrder; }
            set
            {
               if (_selectedRepairOrder == value) return;
                _selectedRepairOrder = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedRepairOrder);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => WriteOffs);

            }
        }
```

The Repair order class:

```
public class RepairOrder
    {

        public string ControlNumber { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public string Schedule { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        private List<WriteOff> _myWriteOffs;

        public List<WriteOff> GetMyWriteOffs()
        {

            return _myWriteOffs;
        }

        public void AddMyWriteOff(WriteOff value)
        { _myWriteOffs.Add(value); }


        public RepairOrder(string CN, string SC, double VL)
        {
            ControlNumber = CN;
            Schedule = SC;
            Value = Math.Round(VL, 2);
            Note = null;
            _myWriteOffs = new List<WriteOff>();
        }

        public RepairOrder()
        {
            _myWriteOffs = new List<WriteOff>();
        }

        public static RepairOrder FromCSV(string CSVLine, string Sched)
        {
            string[] values = CSVLine.Split(',');
            RepairOrder rep = new RepairOrder();
            rep.ControlNumber = values[2];
            rep.Value = Math.Round(double.Parse(values[5]),2);
            rep.Age = int.Parse(values[4]);
            rep.Schedule = Sched;
            return rep;
        }



    }
```

The Write Off Class:

```
public class WriteOff
    {
        public string Account { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double WriteOffAmount { get; set; }

        public WriteOff(string Acct, string Desc, double Amount)
        {
            Account = Acct;
            Description = Desc;
            WriteOffAmount = Amount;
        }
    }
```

This is the method the "Add Write off button is bound too.

```
double WOA;
            if (SelectedAccount == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a Write off Account, Description and amount", "Incorrect Write Off Information", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return;
            }
            if (SelectedWODescription == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a Write off Account, Description and amount", "Incorrect Write Off Information", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return;
            }
            if (WriteOffAmount == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a Write off Account, Description and amount", "Incorrect Write Off Information", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                WOA = Double.Parse(WriteOffAmount);
                if (WOA == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Write off can not be $0.00", "Incorrect Write Off Amount", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                    return;
                }
            }

            //Check if there is a selected repair order
            if (SelectedRepairOrder == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a Repair Order to write this off to", "No RO Selected", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                return;
            }

            WOA = Double.Parse(WriteOffAmount);
            WriteOff tempWO = new WriteOff(SelectedAccount, SelectedWODescription, WOA);
            SelectedRepairOrder.AddMyWriteOff(tempWO);
            WriteOffs.Add(tempWO);
            //MessageBox.Show(SelectedAccount + Environment.NewLine + SelectedWODescription + Environment.NewLine + WriteOffAmount, "Test", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            //MessageBox.Show(tempWO.Account + Environment.NewLine + tempWO.Description + Environment.NewLine + tempWO.WriteOffAmount, ToString());

        }
```

What do I need to do to make the "Write Off" data grid automatically populate with the write off added?  As it works now, if I select another line in the repair order grid and go back to the first, the new write off shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me again :]

After calling  `WriteOffs.Add(tempWO);`

Just add `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => WriteOffs);`

Comment: As usual your amazing! I was not thinking NotifyOfPropertyChange() as a command as much as something performed from with in the setters and getters (Java Speak). I am loving C# and WPF so much better then Java, but the change in how things are handled are killing me.  This actually helped me solve another similar glitch I was having!

Comment: Glad I hear that :] 

And glad I could help :)